# Extract last record inserted for each key identifier

Tags: performance, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with this schema

```
ID, int primary key
PathKey, string not null
InsertDate, datetime not null
Value, int not null
```

- In the table there are a medium-large number of records. 1632 different pathkey and 645627 total records
- The PathKey is not unique (because I store also the old values).
- You can identify a record with the ID or a PathKey with the
  InsertDate.

I am developing a query to extract the last record for each path key, and this is the query I am using but is ugly and incredible slow.

```
SELECT *
FROM ArchiveData
WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT (
                SELECT TOP 1 ID
                FROM ArchiveData
                WHERE PathKey = AD.PathKey
                ORDER BY [InsertDate] DESC
                ) AS ArchiveDataID
        FROM ArchiveData AS AD
        GROUP BY PathKey
        )
ORDER BY PathKey
```

Any suggestions to improve, at least, the performance?

Comment: Are your ID values 'strictly increasing' (i.e. does the most recent date record also have the largest ID)?

Comment: Yes, the identity is set as auto incremental

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [CTE (Supported by SQL Server)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would help separate the logic of the query better than the sub-select in the from clause. Using the auto-increment ID is also something that can simplify the query.

Consider the following:

```
with MostRecent as (
    select max(ID) as ID
    from ArchiveData
    group by PathKey
)
select *
from ArchiveData inner join MostRecent on MostRecent.ID = ArchiveData.ID
order by PathKey
```

The above should reduce the number of joins a lot, and use a better key for the joins that are done.

Comment: SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1328 ms,  elapsed time = 880 ms. Enough for what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to suggest using the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, which allows you to number returned rows using the ordering you provide.

Here is a complete query that uses the ROW_NUMBER function. I also removed the `SELECT *` and replaced them with the column names.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    PathKey, 
    InsertDate, 
    Value
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        PathKey, 
        InsertDate, 
        Value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PathKey ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Row
    FROM ArchiveData
) A
WHERE A.Row = 1
```

You could also use a CTE or temp table to store the results of the inner query. I would recommend using a temp table for the reasons outlined in this [DBA.SE question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table)

Here is an example using a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #ArchivedData
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PathKey VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    InsertDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    Value INT NOT NULL,
    Row INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #ArchivedData
SELECT 
    ID,
    PathKey, 
    InsertDate, 
    Value,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PathKey ORDER BY ID DESC) AS Row
FROM ArchiveData

SELECT 
    ID,
    PathKey, 
    InsertDate, 
    Value
FROM #ArchivedData
WHERE Row = 1

DROP TABLE #ArchivedData
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it but it's slower than rolfl answer.